# Struts2 select tag disabled but with scroll

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have the following code:

```xml
<tr>
            <td class = "tdLabel">
                <label class = "label"
                         for = "saveOrUpdate">Position:
                </label>
                <s:select list = "positionsMap" 
                          name = "positionSelectedIds"
                         value = "selectedPositions.{positionId}" 
                      disabled = "true"
                          size = "1"/>
            </td>
</tr>
```

With this, I have selected positions displayed correctly and disabled. But what I would like to achieve is to have the selection disabled but with enabled scroll bar so that I can see more than 1 selections (I have size 1) and if possible not in pale style. Is this possible? I assume that `disabled` does not fit in my case.
An alternative that would fit for me is just to display the selected properties like:

```xml
<s:property value="selectedPositions.{positionName}"/>
```

The problem with this is that I have the position names displayed but surrounded by `{}`

From action:

```xml
private Map<Long,String> positionsMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();
private List<Long> positionSelectedIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
private List<Position> selectedPositions = new ArrayList<Position>();
// getters and setters
```

Any help would be appreciated, if you need more info or you notice mistakes please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Iterate them using S2 tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this:

```
<select size=4>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi" disabled>Audi</option>
</select>
```

then you can not get it with `s:select`. You must build a select manually with `s:iterator` and `s:if`.

If you want to use `s:select`, you need to use some `java script` to disable certain options after document is loaded. In this case pass the value of the disabled items to the page.